# Provide DI container from outside for self hosted .NET Core MVC application

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac, asp.net-core-1.0

Is it possible to provide configured DI container into the WebHostBuilder ?

```
 var host = new WebHostBuilder()
                .UseKestrel()
                .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .UseIISIntegration()
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .UseApplicationInsights()
                .Build();

            host.Start();
```

I have singleton object running/managing some background jobs. I would like to have it managed via DI container (eg. Autofac), which is exposing management interface via REST API.

My idea is to create DI container outside WebHostBuilder, get from it Singleton, start it's job managment thread and pass it to the WebHostBuilder as a dependency to Controller to expose it via REST Interface.

Is it possible to achieve or my approach is completely wrong ?

Comment: Why not add it to service collection as singleton during startup and activate it there or on configure

Comment: That is actually brilliant idea. I have added additional parameter to method Configure. Singleton get's resolved by DI and I'm just activating it there. Thanks!

Comment: One question though. Is there any hook I can use to gracefully shutdown my background jobs?

Comment: gracefully shut down when?

Comment: For ex, set cancellation token for the tasks inside to complete the jobs and exit properly.

Comment: Wrap try/catch, listen for cancellation exception, and then take necessary action.

Comment: By any chance, did you mean gracefully shutting down your back ground jobs when the application is shutting down?. If so, you can use IApplicationLifetime. You need to inject it to Configure method and register call backs for Application shutdown.